# Camel not removing exchanges from Seda queue in case of error

Tags: java, apache-camel

I have a two Camel routes in two separate route builders, this is their simplified version:

```
onException(Exception.class)
  .handled(true).log(LoggingLevel.ERROR, "${exception.stacktrace}");

from("direct:route1")
  .routeId("Route1")
  .wireTap("seda:route2")
  .bean(myBean, "createRequest1")
  .to("http4://host1/somePath")
  .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, ">> Response R1 >> ${body}");

-----------
onException(Exception.class)
  .handled(true).log(LoggingLevel.ERROR, "${exception.stacktrace}");

from("seda:route2")
  .routeId("Route2")
  .bean(myBean, "createRequest2")
  .to("http4://host2/someOtherPath")
  .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, ">> Response R2 >> ${body}");
```

In Route2, http4 step, I am getting TimeoutExceptions so the process is interrupted. The exception is logged as expected, but the `Exchange` is not removed from the Seda queue, its size is being increased for every Exception thrown in the route.

I would expect all failed Exchanges to be removed from the queue, however that is not happening. Is there something wrong with the error handling?

If somebody can share her/his thoughts will be helping.